# Is it possible to use groupProperty with mongoDB and Grails?

Tags: mongodb, grails

I'm trying to use groupProperty with MongoDB in a Grails project. I'm on version 2.3.2 of Grails and version 3.0.1 of the MongoDB plugin.

My criteria looks like this:

```
def groupedScenarios = Scenario.withCriteria {
    eq 'scenarioVersion', {
        projections {
            max 'scenarioVersion'
        }
    }
    projections {
        groupProperty 'scenarioNumber'
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find the scenarios where the scenarioVersion is highest for a given scenarioNumber. I don't even know if my criteria are correct yet, hence my explanation of my end goal.

The error returned is

```
No signature of method: <my service>.groupProperty() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [scenarioNumber]
Possible solutions: getProperty(java.lang.String), hasProperty(java.lang.String). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: <my service>.groupProperty() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [scenarioNumber]
Possible solutions: getProperty(java.lang.String), hasProperty(java.lang.String)
```

Some searching has suggested groupProperty wasn't supported, but the docs for version 6 of the plugin suggest it is now.

Am I doing anything wrong with my criteria? If it's a plugin version issue, does anyone know when groupProperty became supported by the Grails MongoDB plugin?

I've really struggled to find documentation about previous versions of Grails  plugins - am I missing something? The plugin page at https://www.grails.org/plugin/mongodb doesn't allow me to look at old releases as far as I can tell. Really frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using "mongo's native" query syntax for such tasks.

From my experience GORM for mongo is fine for simple dynamic-finders which work the same way on any DB out there, but if you need to fire a DB-specific query you have to go native, as `GORM criteria` is too SQL-biased.

So, you query could look something like:

```
def groupedScenarios = Scenario.collection.aggregate(
  [ $group:[ _id:'_id', maxNumber:[ $max:scenarioNumber ] ] ]
).results()
```

I'm not a mongo-expert, so you have to assemble a proper query yourself, as per [mongo ref doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I was after but your answer showed me the light and I did what I've been avoiding for ages and wrote a mapreduce function. Many thanks.